# How to extract a specific data from a vector of uint8_t that contains a vector of string messages

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to extract data from a `vector<uint8_t>` that contains strings from a `vector<string>`.  The data part I want to extract are hexa numbers.  It will be easier to extract the data from the `vector<string>` but unfortunately it's in a `vector<uint8_t>`.

I have tried to use `std::search()` but it doesn't seem to work, and also I have tried without using `std::search()`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

std::vector<std::string> messages = {
"67 odd=123; time=0; hex=0x88 0x66 0x2d 0x20 0x10 0x11",
"65 odd=123; time=0; hex=0x88 0x66 0x4e 0x30 0x10 0x11"
};

std::vector<uint8_t> byteVector;
for (const std::string& message: messages) {
  byteVector.insert(byteVector.end(), message.begin(), message.end());
}

// Search for the pattern "0x88 0x66" in byteVector
std::vector<uint8_t> pattern = {0x88, 0x66};
auto it = std::search(byteVector.begin(), byteVector.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end());

if (it != byteVector.end()) {
  while (it != byteVector.end()) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pattern.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(*(it + i)) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Move to the next occurrence of the pattern
    it = std::search(it + 1, byteVector.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end());
  }
 } else {
   std::cout << "Pattern '0x88 0x66 not found.'" << std::endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Right now, I am hitting "Pattern '0x88 0x66 not found.'"

Comment: Are you aware that one of your arrays' contents includes the ***text string*** `"0x88 0x66"`, which is, in hexadecimal: `30 78 38 38 20 30 78 36 36`. Attempting to find the sequence in `88 66`, hiding somewhere in there, will not succeed no matter which straightforward search algorithm you attempt to use. You will need to change your search target of `88 66`, in hexadecimal to the ***text string*** "0x88 0x66". Then, your chances of success will improve greatly.

Comment: Also note that unless your `messages` strings are all the exact same length, the way you are putting them into `byteVector` won't let you easily extract them back out later, you would have to manually scan through the whole `byteVector` *parsing* the bytes to figure out where one string ends and the next begins. When serializing strings into a container, you should also include a way to delimit the strings, either my placing their lengths in front of their data, or by putting a unique delimiter in between each string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no I can't touch the way the message is set up, just passing through the byVector and grab it and extract that hex numbers from there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik change the messages, can't change the contents of the message? this part like this:?  `std::vector<uint8_t> pattern = {88, 66};`

Comment: @Bebe I wasn't suggesting you change the `messages` strings, just how you are putting them into `byteVector` to make later extraction from `byteVector` easier on yourself.

Comment: @Bebe Sam already explained why `std::search()` is not working.  You are searching for the wrong thing. The 2-byte sequence `0x88 0x66` doesn't exist in `byteVector`, because what you actually stored is the 9-byte byte sequence `0x30 0x78 0x38 0x38 0x20 0x30 0x78 0x36 0x36` instead, ie the bytes for the ASCII string `"0x88 0x66"`. For what you are attempting to do, you will have to *extract* the `hex=...` substring from the data, and then *parse* it to convert the 9 characters `"0x88 0x66"` back into the 2 bytes `0x88 0x66` before you can then compare them to your `pattern`...

Comment: @Bebe ... and that then goes back to my earlier comment, because extracting those `hex=...` substrings from `byteVector` is going to be difficult because of the bad way you populated `byteVector` to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you I think i know what to do now!

Comment: Sorry, @bebe, but we don't write code for other people on Stackoverflow, we only answer questions. Do you understand why your search approach does not work? You don't need someone to write your program for you. You need to learn and understand the fundamental reason ***why*** this search attempt does not work. If you actually understand ***why*** it is, then you will know and understand how to write the search correctly. Which part of our explanation is still unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes I got it to work from the suggested comments, no I got it, i am posting my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

   std::vector<std::string> messages = {
   "67 odd=123; time=0; hex=0x88 0x66 0x2d 0x20 0x10 0x11",
   "65 odd=123; time=0; hex=0x88 0x66 0x4e 0x30 0x10 0x11"
  };

  std::vector<uint8_t> byteVector;
  for (const std::string& message: messages) {
    std::string dataPart = message.substr(message.find("hex=") + 5);

    std::istringstream hexStream(dataPart);
    int hexValue;
    while (hexStream >> std::hex >> hexValue) {
      byteVector.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(hexValue));
    }
  }
 
  // Search for the pattern "0x88 0x66" in byteVector
  std::vector<uint8_t> pattern = {0x88, 0x66};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < byteVector.size() - pattern.size() + 1; ++i) {
    bool match = true;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < pattern.size(); ++j) {
      if (byteVector[i + j] != pattern[j]) {
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match) {
    for (size_t k = i; k < i + pattern.size(); ++k) {
      std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(byteVector[k]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
   }
  }
  return 0;
}
```